# Jquerymobile data-split-icon position

Tags: javascript, listview, jquery-mobile

Im trying to move the data-split-icon in a listview to the left side instead of on the right side but cannot figure out how to solve this.
Other than this i want the list-view-items to have the same look/functionality, problem is JQM juts defaults first link as list-item link and second link as the data-split icon, i would want it to be the other way around.

I would imagine you should be able to maybe do a change in the .css file somewhere but I have no idea where.

BR Tomas

Comment: Hi! Could you provide some code?